# how can i set border as well as background image to a textview in android?

Tags: android

[as shown in image i want the border outside image but the image changes everytime as it comes from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiVNc.png)I hava a textview in which the background images come from database, apart from that image i also want to add border to textview background.
I have used RoundedBitmapDrawable to set background image for textview.

```
RoundedBitmapDrawable img=  getDrawableFromName(getResources().getString(R.string.not_available));

//this line sets the border from .xml file.
mytextview.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.holiday_dateborder));

//this line sets image to background
mytextview.setBackgroundDrawable(img);


//my method to get image.
 public RoundedBitmapDrawable getDrawableFromName(String name){

        Resources res = getResources();
        int resourceId =getResources().getIdentifier(name,"drawable",getPackageName());
        Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,resourceId);
        RoundedBitmapDrawable dr = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(res, src);
        try {
            if(dr.getBitmap()!=null)
            {
                return dr;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: can u give some more details, what type of button exactly you need? Or some code which you are using currently?

Comment: I have uploaded the image please check.

Comment: you need a button like that? as in the image? As image just looks like the box image on a white background.

Comment: Ya....i need a black border shown in image surrounding the image....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_border_grey"
        android:padding="2dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**bg_border_grey.xml** add it in your drawable folder

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Will it work?? If i change background of my textview programmatically from java file.

Comment: @SamirBagaria you are using it wrong.
//this line sets the border from .xml file.
mytextview.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.holiday_dateborder));
this should be applied on the RelativeLayout and not on textView itself. Doing this your next drawable assignment is removing the previous one

Comment: Check my xml code, how I have used, the border xml will be assigned to RelativeLayout and the other drawable which you are getting from server will go to your textview

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this as a background for a round border on text view:-

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="ring">

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
     android:color="@color/blue" />
</shape>
```

Comment: replace that setBackgroundDrawable for setting the holiday_border by setBackground  it will work then